# Gigabyte BRIX GB-BLCE-4000C with M.2 NVMe SSD

Tags: nvme

According to the [specs](https://www.gigabyte.com/Mini-PcBarebone/GB-BLCE-4000C-rev-10/sp#sp) the Gigabyte BRIX GB-BLCE-4000C has an internal M.2 port. This port is taken by a Wi-Fi and Bluetooth card. For I do require neither Wi-Fi nor Bluetooth for this computer, is it possible to use this port with an NVMe M.2 SSD card, such as a Samsung 970 EVO Plus or wouldn't this work?

I do not own this PC yet and therefore cannot simply try it out.

Comment: Please specify the size of M.2 it supports.

Comment: I do not know more than written within these specs, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**No, it doesn't support NVMe drives.**

It does support M.2 **SATA** SSDs of the "2230" form factor. That's what "NGFF" in the specification quoted below means:

> 1 x PCIe M.2 NGFF 2230 A-E key slot occupied by the WiFi+BT card

So, yes, you can remove the WiFi+BT card and insert a SATA SSD M.2 drive of the specific size **if you can find one**, good luck with that. Adapters do exist but you can't fit a larger one where there simply isn't space for it. And in any case the NVMe standard is different an not compatible. Your Samsung EVO is NOT supported in this slot and it wouldn't fit anyway.

Answer (score -1):

*I asked my dealer. He says:*

In theory it should work, however there might be not enough space for the SSD physically: There are only 57 mm until the LAN port on the board. My NVMe is 80 mm long.

It might work with an adapter, but I didn't try that.